# How to pre-load data into laravel session?

Tags: laravel

I wish to pre-load database reference data into the session whenever any of the pages loads.

Scenario:
1) any of the page load, check the session if the data exist or not.
2) if yes, do nothing, if not load the data in database into the session.

Any idea where i should code it or how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform this on every page view (be sure it's really every request that is coming to your application) you can create a `__constructor` in your main Controller (Http/Controllers/Controller.php) and fill your session there.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct () { 
        // fill session here
    }
}
```

Another way of course is a middleware. The advantage here is the "disadvantage", too - you'll have to insert the middleware in every single controller you want this check to perform, but you can choose some routes/controllers that shouldn't do this check.

```
class FillSessionData {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // fill session here 
    return $next($request);
}
```

If you go with the middleware solution, you'll need to add it to your Http/kernel.php in the $routeMiddleware array:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //.....
    'sessionSetter' => 'App\Http\Middleware\FillSessionData',
 ];
```

and include it in the controller you want this check to perform, in the constructor as well with:

```
 $this->middleware('sessionSetter');
```